# Swicthmap in rxjs doesnt cancel the previous request

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5, switchmap

I am basically calling an API on keyup event of a textbox using switchmap. The problem that I am facing is that switchmap doesn't cancel the previous ongoing API call when a new API call is made

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {fromEvent, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map, switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-debounce-component',
  templateUrl: './debounce-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./debounce-component.component.css']
})
export class DebounceComponentComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }
  @ViewChild('searchinput') ele:ElementRef

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.ele.nativeElement , 'keyup').pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      map(evt=>{

             return evt['target']['value']
      }),
      switchMap(value=>{
        console.log(value);
        return this.createObservable(value);
      }),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    ).subscribe() ;
  }

  createObservable(value):Observable<any>{

    return Observable.create(observer=>{
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/courses/${value}`).then(res=>{
        res.json();
      }).then(body=>{
        observer.next(body);
        observer.complete();
      });
    })

  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using fetch directly instead of the Angular HttpClient? It handles request cancelation automatically

Comment: Agreed, just use Angular's HttpClient

Comment: @A.Chiesa. Actually i am trying to learn rxjs switchmap and as per the docs rxjs switchmap should cancel an ongoing request if a new request get fired. I can use HttpClient but my concern is that why is switchmap not cancelling the ongoing api call when a new api call gets fired

Comment: Switch map is unsubscribing from the previous observable. The problem is not switchmap per se. It's your usage of fetch that doesn't connect the unsubscribe to the cancel request. HttpClient provides an extended implementation

Comment: Thankyou A. Chiesa. Your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's now possible (it wasn't for a long time) to abort requests made with `fetch`, you'll still need an `AbortController` to do so. Fortunately for us, RxJS has implemented an operator called `fromFetch` that handles this for us.

Simply do

```
fromFetch("https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5").pipe(
  switchMap(response => {
```

and it should work as you want!